# How to Hide/show <p:toolbar> onclick of a <p:menuitem>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working with JSF 2.0 and primefaces 3.3. I want to hide/show a toolbar onclick of a menuitem.

Here is the more info.

```
<p:menubar autoSubmenuDisplay="true" style="width:99%">
                    <p:submenu label="Projects">
                        <p:menuitem id="m11" value="Select Product" actionListener="#{menuBean.renderTool}" update="t1" />
                        <p:menuitem id="m12" value="Select Project" />
                        <p:menuitem id="m13" value="Select Contract" />
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:menuitem id="m2" value="Global" />

                    <p:menuitem id="m7" value="Exit" />
                </p:menubar>

                <p:toolbar id="t1" rendered="#{menuBean.renderToolbar}">
                    <p:toolbarGroup align="left" style="height:20px;">
                        <h:outputText value="Projects " />
                        <h:outputText value=" - select Product" />
                    </p:toolbarGroup>
                </p:toolbar>
```

**ManagedBean**

```
private boolean renderToolbar = false;
//getters and setters
public void renderTool(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        System.out.println("inside renderTool method...");
        renderToolbar = true;
    }
```

The actionListener method is executing But, it's not updating or rendering the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add some boolean variable to your bean

```
boolean someBoolean; //+ getter/setter
```

and inside your `renderToolbar` method add

```
someBoolean = !someBoolean; // toggle the disaplay on and off
```

in xhtml change

```
<p:toolbar id="t1" rendered="#{menuBean.renderToolbar}">
```

into

```
<h:panelGroup id="t1">
    <p:toolbar rendered="#{menuBean.someBoolean}">
.
.
.
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am working on this solution. The boolean value is getting updated to true. But, the toolbar is not rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Not much info that you provided.

However, one way to do it is using Javascript with the `onclick` event handler. 
Like this (untested code):

```
<p:toolbar id="toolbarID" />
<p:menu>
    <p:menuitem onclick="$('#toolbarID').toggle();" />
</p:menu>
```

I think primefaces already includes jquery so you should be able to use jquery selectors out of the box.

Comment: Hi Jens, Thank you for the reply. I tried this solution. Its not working for me.

Comment: I guess you already found a solution. Otherwise: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Yes jens, I got the solution from Daniel. Actually, there are no error messages and no action when I use onclick="$('#toolbarID').toggle();" . I am new to Jqery so, I went with the other solution.

Comment: Don't forget to put in the id on the `<p:toolbar>` component. Also verify that this is really the final id. You might have some additional naming container that extends the id (e.g. if it is nested inside a form). Then you could use a different selector maybe like this: `$('input[id$="tollbarID"]').toggle();`

Comment: @Jens when using the `[id=]` lookup in JSF you need to 'escape' the quotes. Please see my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

The solution Daniel provided works using a backing bean. However if showing/displaying some element isn't dependent on data but is more a client-side thing or a simple user controlled element I would advice against using a backing bean. Using a backing bean for client-side stuff causes delays or as a regular user would put it: "It's slow".

In stead use client side things like JavaScript as Jens suggested. Since you're using PrimeFaces you can make use of jQuery. A simple example to demonstrate jQuery's `toggle()`, `show()` and `hide()` functions:

```
<h:form>
    <p:menubar>
        <p:menuitem value="Toggle" onclick="$(&quot;[id='t1']&quot;).toggle()" />
        <p:menuitem value="Show" onclick="$(&quot;[id='t1']&quot;).show()" />
        <p:menuitem value="Hide" onclick="$(&quot;[id='t1']&quot;).hide()" />
    </p:menubar>
</h:form>

<p:toolbar id="t1" />
```

Note that if your `p:toolbar` lives in a container like a form or such the client-side ID is prefixed with the form's ID.